# Uninstalling KB2506143 (WMF 3.0) from Windows 2008R2 with Exchange 2010 SP2 doesn't work

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, exchange-2010, powershell, patch-management

`KB2506143` was installed on `Exchange 2010 SP2` machine on `Windows 2008 R2`. Since `WMF 3.0` was installed `Rollup Updates` cannot be installed as they fail on starting some `PowerShell` scripts. Normal scenario assumes that uninstalling that patch works and you can install `Rollup Updates for Exchange` with no problems. However in my case it didn't work. I went to program and features and uninstalled that patch, was asked to reboot after uninstall. After it gets back from reboot, it reboots itself again and after login WMF 3.0 is back there.
After lots of retrying uninstall I found solution which I will post as an answer to save some time for others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I run the following command to uninstall that patch:

> cmd /c start /w pkgmgr
>   /up:Microsoft-Windows-WinMan-WinIP-Package-TopLevel~31bf3856ad364e35~x86~~7.1.7601.16398
>   /quiet /norestart

or

> cmd /c start /w pkgmgr
>   /up:Microsoft-Windows-WinMan-WinIP-Package-TopLevel~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~7.1.7601.16398
>   /quiet /norestart

To be sure I tried both. What I noticed that after running those, uninstall happened but after reboot it was back there again (so this was no go solution again). So I rerun it and before rebooting I went to Programs and Features / Uninstall and I noticed that after uninstall the patch is still there... but with added Beta 3.0 (KB2506143) in the end. So I uninstalled that and after reboot the patch was gone.

I don't know how BETA got into there, and why it worked the way it worked but it did the trick for me. When I tried to uninstall that patch via Uninstall menu it never showed the BETA. Only by running the commands above it showed there was some beta patch of WMF 3.0 installed.